# How to created input data with Drupal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, drupal, drupal-modules

So, I've been doing programming and HTML for some time now. A lot of it is front end working with CMSs and stylizing. However there's one thing I've been wanting to learn.

When it comes to drupal, how do I go about creating something where a user can enter in text and it appears above? Honestly, I'm not sure if I'm even asking about it correctly. It's something a lot of websites already have so I'm sure it's not too difficult to answer.

The best example might be Basecamp. Essentially what I'm looking to do is that if a user is on a project they are apart of, I want them to write in a little text box (similar to what i'm doing right now) click submit and it appears in a comment section above. Some sort of simple form that links directly to a field I created in drupal.

Yes I do understand there's a comment module that's built into core but I'm looking to create something similar. Or even as similar as a twitter feed. A user just goes to his or her page and has a box for them to write out a small message.

Can someone point me in the right direction as it pertains to Drupal.

Best,
V

Comment: A starting point would be to read about AHAH in Drupal: https://www.drupal.org/node/348475

Answer (score 1):

For data input, websites usually use forms. Drupal provies an [Form API](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/group/form_api/8.2.x) that you use to create forms and process their submission. You then need to process the submitted data and store them in the database. For that you will need [Drupal's database abstraction layer](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Database!database.api.php/group/database/8.2.x). Finally, you will need to build page to display the form and the stored data. A page is the result of a controller method binded to a [route](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Routing!routing.api.php/group/routing/8.2.x). That result can either be a render array (see the [Theme and rende](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/group/theme_render/8.2.x) for more information), or a Symfony [`Response`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/vendor%21symfony%21http-foundation%21Response.php/class/Response/8.2.x) object.